# Установить иконку Qt приложению в обход файла .pro

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio

Нужно задать иконку .exe файлу Qt программы. Во всех найденных решениях сказано, что делается это через файл проекта .pro Но код писался и собирался не в QtCreator, а в Visual Studio, а там файла .pro нету

Comment: Эм, в документации Qt есть такой раздел. [Вот](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html).

Comment: @MrBin в этом разделе всё делается через файл .pro

Comment: "If you do not use qmake, the necessary steps are: first, create an .rc file and run the rc or windres program on the .rc file, then link your application with the resulting .res file." - также можно использовать инструменты msvc. Те же ресурсные файлы. Или спец функции, которые ТАКЖЕ указаны в вышеприведённой ссылке.

Comment: @MrBin "Если вы не используете qmake, необходимо выполнить следующие шаги: сначала создайте файл .rc и запустите программу rc или windres для файла .rc, затем свяжите свое приложение с полученным файлом .res."   - - - - - - - - -  Что значит  "_запустите программу rc или windres для файла .rc, затем свяжите свое приложение с полученным файлом .res_" Как это делается?

Comment: Ресурсы упаковывает msvc за вас. Вам нужно только построить скрипт. [Вот как это делается вручную](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler). Вам осталось загуглить "как указатель ресурсы программы в msvc".

Comment: Обычно в msvc указывается файл ресурсов в котором перечисляются сами ресурсы. Если кликнуть по настройкам проекта и добавить новый файл, то там должен быть Resource file. Если совсем тривиально.